# "Failed to connect to repository" in Jenkins on OSX to GitHub

Tags: macos, github, jenkins

Getting this error when setting up my GitHub repo in Jenkins on a OS X machine.

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://github.com/username/repo.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/repo.git/': Internal SSL engine error encountered during the SSL handshake
```

This has been working before and I've been running build successfully connected to this repo but all of a sudden I started to get this message. Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks

PS. Have looked at the other related questions but they don't have the exact same issue and/or are not on the same platform as me.

Comment: Have you tried to run `git` command manually?

Comment: If I ssh onto the machine and go to the workspace of the job, I'm able to pull from the git repo, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Yes, but try to run it as `jenkins` user. This is not Jenkins's problem, but `git` internal SSL error. Maybe there is invalid SSL certs cache, which you have to purge or whatsoever.

Comment: I ssh as the jenkins user, hmm ok, it worked fine yesterday that is the weird thing.

Comment: Yeah, it happens when website does something at their side. This problem should disappear some time later. You probably should ask this question at "Server Fault".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found what the issue was. I logged into the mac machine with a certain user and started the jenkins.war file from there. It worked fine until I logged out the user, that's when I started to see the problem and why I resolved it by restarting the computer. So as long as I am not logging out the jenkins user, everything is fine.